# How to handle asynchronous nature of RxJS Observables inside Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm new to Angular and the Observables architecture, and I'm having trouble running functions that have asynchronous code.

In the code below, I am using the AngularFire library to obtain information from a basic Firebase Realtime Database. However, when I call the function `searchForCompany()` from one of my components, the observable doesn't load the required data instantly, meaning the HTML elements of my component don't get loaded properly. Am I using the Observables architecture wrong?

```
import { SubscriptionData } from './interface'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SubscriptionService {
  private dbRead: SubscriptionData[];
  private subscriptionData = new SubscriptionData;
  private databasePath = "/companies";
  private databaseRef: AngularFireList<SubscriptionData>;

  constructor(private _database: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.databaseRef = _database.list(this.databasePath);
  }

  searchForCompany(service:String) {
    for (let key of this.dbRead) {
      //Search for name of a company in the Firebase database
      if (key.name == service) {
        this.subscriptionData=key;
        return;
      }
    }

  readDatabase() {
    this.databaseRef.valueChanges().subscribe(data=> {
      this.dbRead = data;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: The following course is an excellent resource for gaining an understanding of rxjs and Observables: https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/rxjs-angular-reactive-development.  Also, it's completely free until the end of April.

Comment: Can you please share your template code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think about observable like about a stream that provides data. Your component should subscribe to this stream. Then a component will receive every new value from the stream.

Some example [here](https://github.com/dnmakarov/angular-showcase-default/blob/master/src/modules/route1/components/users-listing/users-listing.component.ts):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-users-listing',
  templateUrl: './users-listing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users-listing.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class UsersListingComponent {

  // THIS IS A "STREAM" AND YOU NEED TO SUBSCRIBE TO IT IN THE TEMPLATE OR INSIDE CODE
  users$: Observable<UserInterface[]> = this.activatedRoute.data.pipe(
    map(data => data.users),
  );

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

}
```

Let's subscribe to `users$` inside the template

```
<mat-list>
  <!-- "users$ | async" creates a subscription  -->
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let user of (users$ | async)">
    <h3 matLine> {{ user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name }} </h3>
    <p matLine>
      <span> {{user.email}} </span>
    </p>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Regarding to your example. Try to change your service to return an Observable from the method and subscribe to it in your component.
It could be like

```
searchForCompany () {
  return this.databaseRef.valueChanges()
}
```

And subscribe to it in the component, transform received data, etc. It may looks like:

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor (private service: SubscriptionService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.searchForCompany().pipe(
      // SOME ADDITIONAL LOGIC
      // --> WRITE SOME CODE TO DESTROY SUBSCRIPTION HERE <---
    ).subscribe();
  }
}
```

OR create class property - observable. And subscribe to it in template using `async` pipe

```
export class MyComponent {

  propert$ = this.service.searchForCompany().pipe(
    // SOME ADDITIONAL LOGIC
  )
  constructor (private service: SubscriptionService) {}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What do I do if my Observable needs to be used by a separate method within my service? I have tried subscribing to my Observable in a separate method, but this still suffers from the same asynchronous delay problems.

Comment: When you subscribe to observable the Angular does HTTP request. It takes some time to get a response. That's why some delay may occur. But please share at least some code to understand what you are working with.

Comment: I have included more code in my question now. The `searchForCompany()` method is supposed to take in a company name and search through a Firebase Realtime Database to find information associated with that name, and store it in the `subscriptionData`. However, if a component tries to run `readDatabase()` inside my code, and then runs `searchforCompany("myCompany)`, the Observable lags behind and I get errors which say "cannot read property ... of undefined".

Comment: The main problem as I see that you get data from the server asynchronously but then try to access it synchronously. Think of data from the server as "stream". And your component should subscribe to the stream to show data. Refactor your code to be async. I've prepared gist [here](https://gist.github.com/dnmakarov/219ad0b2a7f3e918a076679ebe5c9a4a). Use method  `searchForCompanyObs`, it creates observable (stream) and just use it the component. Implementations can be different but the idea is the same - components should work with async data and try to avoid accessing data with sync manner